# Can I make a url act as an alias for another url

Tags: node.js, express, webserver, cdn

So I need `cdn.ex.com/avatars/:UserID` point to my cloud public file URI which is `https://cloudapi.com/account.cloud.com/files/uploads/avatars/(userid)/avatar.png` (true URL is put)
I don't have any code yet except

```js
app.get('/avatars/:userid', (req, res)=>{
    let userid = req.params.userid
    let uri = `https://cloudapi.com/account.cloud.com/files/uploads/avatars/${userid}/avatar.png`

});
```

So I shall be able to do in html:

```html
<span>Username</span>
<img class="pfp" src="cdn.ex.com/avatars/671856275627525">
```

Instead of having to do

```html
<span>Username</span>
<img class="pfp" src="https://cloudapi.com/account.cloud.com/files/uploads/avatars/671856275627525/avatar.png">
```

Any help on how can I do that?

Comment: If you don't know or if it's impossible please tell me

Comment: What you want is a "proxy" & "url rewriting". You should be able to implement that in express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it,
You use node-fetch to fetch the resource
Then send data as buffer
If its used in  tag it will work, if a user tried going to the link it will work too.
Goto google and search node-fetch then goto its npm and search for Buffer
Then just res.send(buffer) instead of `fileType(buffer)` and remove the last line.
Thanks for **@Marc** for trying to help (in comments)